# Streamlined way of removing multiple characters from string in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to clean up address data within a Pandas dataframe. I would like to remove all commas and periods from the addresses. I have a lambda function that works, but it requires me to use `.replace()` over and over again:

`x.replace(',', '').replace('.', '')` etc.

I have tried to simplify the code and use `.translate({None: ",."})` and the code runs without any errors but the commas and periods are not removed.

Is there a more streamlined way to accomplish this? I would also like to remove things like 'ave', 'blvd', 'boulevard', etc. and I would like to be able to do it without using `.replace()` for every item I need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `operator.methodcaller` like this:

```
from operator import methodcaller

replacements = [(',', ''), ('.', '')]
methods = [methodcaller('replace', r[0], r[1]) for r in replacements]

string = 'change, me. please'
for m in methods:
    string = m(string)

string
```

> "change me please"

This could be applied to a dataframe as follows:

```
def replace_(string):
    for m in methods:
        string = m(string)
    return string

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': 'silly.strings,,, a.,whole.. few.,dd'.split()})

print(df)

               col1
0  silly.strings,,,
1        a.,whole..
2           few.,dd


df.col1.apply(replace_)

0    sillystrings
1          awhole
2           fewdd
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am having trouble getting this solution to work. I copied the code (including replacements and methods from the first block) into a Python file and ran it, but when I print the dataframe from your example, the commas and periods are still in the strings. Could this be because of a difference in Python version? I am using Python 3.

Comment: This is probably because you are not actually changing the original dataframe. Try doing this: `df.col1 = df.col1.apply(replace_)` . Then your column will be overwritten with the replacements.

Comment: That was exactly it. Works perfectly now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cheers! It's cool to find a use case for methodcaller, I just learned about it the other week in the book Fluent Python